# basic input validation with java.io

Tags: java, eclipse, validation, input

I'm a beginner programmer, I have been writing code for about three weeks now. I want to make a simple program that asks for user input temperature and tells whether or not the user has fever (temperature higher than 39). I also want to validate the user input, meaning that if the user types "poop" or "!@·R%·%" (symbol gibberish), the program will output the phrase "invalid input". I'm trying to use the try/catch statements, this is my code:

```
package feverPack;

import java.io.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        try{
        InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(inStream);

        System.out.println("please input patient temperature in numbers");
        String numone =stdIn.readLine();}

        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("invalid input");
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e){
            System.out.println("invalid input");
        }
        int temp = Integer.parseInt(numone) ;


        System.out.println("Your temperature is " + temp + "ºC");


        if (temp > 39) {
            System.out.println("You have fever! Go see a doctor!");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Don't worry, your temperature is normal");
        }
    }
}
```

There is an error in line 22 (when i transform numone into a temp) saying "numone cannot be resolved to a variable", as I am a beginner I don't really know what to do, please help.

Comment: The answer has been given already, but look here for some more information: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/VariableScope.htm

Comment: so i did what the answer said, added that extra line, no more errors, still the program doesn't fulfill its function, by this i mean, when i type phrases or letters as input the program still crashes instead of going with the catch statement

Comment: place `int temp = Integer.parseInt(numone) ;` inside the `try` block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the declaration of `numone` outside the try block. Basically, `numone` was `declared` within the `scope` of the `try` block and was not available outside the scope of the `try` block, so moving it out would give it a wider visibility.

```
String numone = null;
int temp = 0;
try
{
...
numone = stdIn.readLine();
temp = Integer.parseInt(numone) ;
System.out.println("Your temperature is " + temp + "ºC");
if (temp > 39) {
      System.out.println("You have fever! Go see a doctor!");
 }
else{
    System.out.println("Don't worry, your temperature is normal");
}
}
catch(..)
{
...
}
```

Comment: tried that man, it comes up with a second error saying "syntax error on tokens: delete this tokens", take into account I have checked and String is written correctly.

Comment: Can you please Update your question with what you have tried.

Comment: scratch that, dumb mistake, but still when i write "no" as an input the program crashes

Comment: Yes thats a programming error, you expect `numone` to be an `integer` and you enter a `string` which cannot be parsed into an integer. It would throw you an `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: i thought that was the whole point of catch, to avoid the crashes and instead posting a message like i did in the code

Comment: works, one more question man, the program outputs the line "invalid input" as planned, but still outputs the rest of the phrases in the program (your temperature is ...) (don't worry...) as if i had written 0 as the input, do you know how i can change this?

Comment: perfect, is there a way to loop the code back to input in case of error?

Comment: I guess this question has been answered here, the answer to your next question lies here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130217/how-to-loop-user-input-until-an-integer-is-inputted. If you still have specific doubts kindly open a new question.